# same comment list for two posts

Tags: comments, plugin-wpml

I've an unique problem, I'm using WPML to translate my website.

WPML takes post and duplicates it, so that translation becomes another post. Thus keeping Gallery/Comments/Ratings separate.

I'm on the quest to unite Gallery/Comments/Ratings for all languages.

Problem is with comments, because wp-list-comments function doesn't accept post ID as an argument.

What are my options? how do I unite comments of two posts? given that I know ID of parent and ID of translation?

I think this is an interesting question :)

ty!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [get_comments()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) instead. The code in [this forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-all-comments-of-a-comment_post_id#post-2003234) gives an example of how you'd do that:

```
<?php
$recent_comments = get_comments( array('post_id' => $newest_post_id,) );

foreach ($recent_comments as $comment)
{
?>
<?php
$comment_id = get_comment($comment->comment_ID);
$author = $comment_id->comment_author;
$commentdate = $comment_id->comment_date;
$content = $comment_id->comment_content;
?>
<p><?php echo $author; echo $commentdate;?></p>
<p><?php echo $content;?></p>
<?php
} ?>
```

Best of luck!

Comment: although this might work on a mono-lingual site, this is definitely not going to work on a site with WPML enabled. Maybe when you change the `'post_id'` on line 2 with `icl_object_id($post->ID, 'post', true, 'en'));`, it can work, but I have not tested this at all

Comment: I used icl_object_id but it still doesn't work... I don't get comments on child posts, but on parents post it works fine event though post_id I have same. Even if I hardcode parent post ID it still doesn't show comments.